# Will Java 8 be able to have another release of Swing?

Tags: swing, java-platform-module-system, java-8

Taking into consideration Project Jigsaw for Java 8 (to modularize the JDK), will a "new" Swing Framework be able to be taken into **consideration**?

*Consideration* means:

- someone actually rewriting it
- including it into a JDK release

I'm thinking, since modules can be included into the JDK, a new framework for Swing can be created and delivered for use to new applications developers, while, for the legacy applications, the current Swing framework would be included.

Would rewriting a new Swing and including it into the new JDK be an option for Java 8? (What are your opinions and considerations to take into account for this *task* ?)

Comment: I **highly** doubt that this will find its way into Java 8. *Even* if it's wanted and planned (which I'm not sure of), I'm pretty sure that such a project would not be done in time for Java 8, which is expected relatively soon. Java 8 should deliver all the missing features that Java 7 didn't include and that's already a pretty long list.

Comment: will it be technically doable even if not practically accessible?

Comment: If Jigsaw can do what it is said to do (i.e. allow real modularity, *including* incompatible updates that don't break older versions), then it will technically doable.

Comment: On the other hand: If you want to do an incompatible break from earlier versions, then why restrict yourself to Swing? You could just as easily switch to an entirely different system altogether (SWT, for example).

Comment: was using Swing as an example; could be anything else. the important thing i was looking for is, if the new JDK modularity provides the ability to pack Swing for old applications and SWT (for example) for new applications

Comment: Java 8 will not have include project JigSaw as stated here: http://mreinhold.org/blog/late-for-the-train

Answer (score 2):

It was not included in Java 8, and is highly unlikely that it will even be considered for Java 9.

According this [JavaFX page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6), JavaFX is the replacement for Swing:

> 6. Is JavaFX replacing Swing as the new client UI library for Java SE?
>
> Yes. However, Swing will remain part of the Java SE specification for
>   the foreseeable future, and therefore included in the JRE. While we
>   recommend developers to leverage JavaFX APIs as much as possible when
>   building new applications, it is possible to extend a Swing
>   application with JavaFX, allowing for a smoother transition.

In addition, [Project Jigsaw is now targeted for Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).